# How to find index position of textbox array by clicking the mouse

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a textbox array

```
 _textBox = new TextBox[]
 { 
        textBox1, 
        textBox2,
        textBox3,
        textBox4,
        textBox5, 
        textBox6, 
        textBox7, 
        textBox8, 
        textBox9 
  };
```

I move up/down in this array by keystroke with this methode:

```
    private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            if (KeyIndex < RowsLimit - 1)
                ++KeyIndex;
            else
            {
                if (KeyIndex != 7)
                    paymntgrp.Visible = false;
                SaveBtn.Select();
                KeyIndex = 0;
                return;
            }
            _textBox[KeyIndex].SelectionStart = 0;
            _textBox[KeyIndex].SelectionLength = _textBox[KeyIndex].Text.Length;
            _textBox[KeyIndex].Select();
            if (KeyIndex != 7)
                paymntgrp.Visible = false;
            else
                paymntgrp.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                if (KeyIndex > 0)
                    --KeyIndex;
                _textBox[KeyIndex].SelectionStart = 0;
                _textBox[KeyIndex].SelectionLength = _textBox[KeyIndex].Text.Length;
                _textBox[KeyIndex].Select();
                if (KeyIndex != 7)
                    paymntgrp.Visible = false;
                else
                    paymntgrp.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I click the mouse randomly in one of textbox Keyindex remains the same and continues from where it was.

How can I set the Keyindex to the position of mouse.?

Should I write under each textbox Keyindex = 0, Keyindex= 1 ...? (Under a method Mouse_Click for ex)

Or there is more effective method ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work (assumes KeyIndex is a class variable)

```
private void textBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;

    KeyIndex = Array.IndexOf(_textBox, txtBox);
}
```

Even better is to use the GotFocus() event.
This will handle tabbing to the control as well as clicking:

```
private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;

    KeyIndex = Array.IndexOf(_textBox, txtBox);
}
```

Comment: When I use that methode KeyIndex gets a value of -1. It search the index of TxtBox in _textBox. My objectif is to determine in wich textbox is my cursor when I click the mouse. By keystroke i count up/down the Keyindex but when I click as in VB I don't know the way to update the Keyindex with it's new location.

Comment: I tested it in C#, but not with VB.  If the GotFocus events for the different textboxes in the array are tied to the same handler (from within the designer code), it should work just fine.

Comment: It's for c#. In VB you have the index build in Textbox if you create an array of textBox. For ex: You create a textbox you copy/paste this textbox in the same object (frame or form) VB ask you if you want create an index for this textbox. You can use this index.